# Buffered Reader Hanging in Java

Tags: java, client, bufferedreader, server, printwriter

I have been tasked with making a simple Java server for one of my programming assignments.  This, I had no trouble with.  The server is essentially a jukebox that stores data about music.  (It doesn't actually store any music for the purpose of the assignment)  Clients should be able to interact with this server to add songs, see the list of songs, and increment a songs popularity.  After doing one of these things, the client is disconnected.  This, I had no problem implementing.  I made a simple multi-threaded server with sockets and server sockets.  I had tested it in telnet and all of the desired functionality worked perfectly.  My problem arises from some testing we have to do.  In order to officially test the server, we are to make a java class that just creates a bunch of client sockets and has them interact with the server.  This is an example.

```
public class LikeTunesServerTest    {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    try {

        Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 12010);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        out.println("0");  // add tune
        out.println("The Beatles");
        out.println("Yellow Submarine");
        out.flush();
        client.close();

        client = new Socket("localhost", 12010);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        out.println("2"); // request all tunes in alphabetical order
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        client.close();

    }

    catch (IOException e)   {

        System.out.println("e");

    }
}
}
```

As far as I am aware, the first client successfully completes its interaction and exits out.  Then, the second client connects but the program then just hangs.  The program should print out The Beatles/nYellow Submarine/n0 .  I am guessing this has to do with my while loop for the BufferedReader, but honestly I have no idea, I am not the best with the JAVA IO I learned.  If anyone could help me deduce what is causing the hang and why nothing gets printed out, I would be grateful.  For reference, here is a snippet of the server program that shows what the server does to handle the clients.

```
 try    {

        // Open I/O

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingConnection.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintStream(incomingConnection.getOutputStream());

        // Ask for input (For Telnet Testing)

        //out.println("Welcome to the LikeTunes Server!.");
        //out.println("Type 0 to add a tune to the list.");
        //out.println("Type 1 to like an existing Tune.");
        //out.println("Type 2 to view the list of Tunes in alphabetical order.");
        //out.println("Type 3 to view the list of Tunes in order of popularity.");
        try {

            final int temp = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            // Add a Tune to the TuneLst

            if (temp == 0)  {

                // Get Tune to be added
                // TuneList method is synchronised to prevent duplicates

                //out.println("Please input the name of the artist.");
                String artistName = new String(in.readLine());
                //out.println("Please input the name of the Tune.");
                String title = new String(in.readLine());

                // If the client leaves an artist's name or title blank

                if (artistName.equals("") || title.equals(""))  {

                    out.println("5");
                }

                // Otherwise, add the Tune

                else    {

                    successCheck = LikeTunesServer.tl.addTune(artistName,title);

                    // Tune was added successfully 

                    if (successCheck == 1)
                    out.println("Request Completed, closing server");

                    // Tune was a duplicate

                    else
                    out.println("Tune was a duplicate, closing server");
                }
            }

            // Like a Tune on the TuneList

            else if (temp == 1) {

                // Get Tune to be liked
                // TuneList method is synchronised to prevent incorrect Tune likes

                //out.println("Please input the name of the artist.");
                String artistName = new String(in.readLine());
                //out.println("Please input the name of the Tune.");
                String title = new String(in.readLine());

                // If the client leaves an artist's name or title blank

                if (artistName.equals("") || title.equals(""))  {

                    out.println("5");
                }

                // Otherwise, like the Tune

                else    {

                    successCheck = LikeTunesServer.tl.likeTune(artistName,title);

                    // Tune was liked successfully

                    if (successCheck == 1)
                    out.println("Request Completed, closing server");

                    // Tune was not there to like

                    else
                    out.println("Could not like Tune, it does not exist on the server yet!");
                }
            }

            // List Tunes Alphabetically

            else if (temp == 2) {

                String result = new String(LikeTunesServer.tl.listAlphabetically());
                out.println(result);
                out.println("Request Completed, closing server");
            }

            // List Tunes by Popularity

            else if (temp == 3) {

                String result = new String(LikeTunesServer.tl.listByLikes());
                out.println(result);
                out.println("Request Completed, closing server");
            }

            // Client made an unrecognised request

            else    {

                out.println("7");
            }
        }
```

Methods from Tunelist.java

```
    public String listAlphabetically()  {

    String result = new String();
    Tune currentTune = theListAlph;

    // Loops through the alphabetical list concatenating the Tune's info to the result string

    for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)  {

        if  (i == 0)    {

            result = currentTune.returnTune();

        }

        else    {

            result = result.concat(currentTune.returnTune());

        }

        currentTune = currentTune.nextAlph;

    }

    return result;

}



 public synchronized int addTune(String artistName, String title)   {

    // If the list is empty, add the first Tune

    int temp = 0;
    if  (theListAlph == null)   {

        Tune newNode = new Tune(artistName, title);
        theListAlph = newNode;
        theListPop = newNode;
        temp = 1;

    }

    // Otherwise, begin searching this List for the new Tune's correct lexicographical position in the Linked List

    else    {

        Tune currentTune = theListAlph;
        while (temp == 0)   {

            String testArtist = currentTune.artistName;
            String newArtist = artistName;
            int compare = newArtist.compareTo(testArtist);

            // This artist of the new Tune comes before the tested artist alphabetically

            if (compare < 0)    {

                Tune newNode = new Tune(artistName, title);

                // If the tested Tune was the first Tune in the alphabetical List, insert the new Tune as the new beginning of the alphabetical Linked List

                if (theListAlph == currentTune) {

                    insertNewFirst(newNode, currentTune, theListPop);

                }

                // Inserting the new Tune in all other locations in the alphabetical Linked List

                else    {

                    insertBeforeNotFirst(newNode, currentTune, theListPop);

                }

                temp = 1;

            }

            // The new artist is the same as the tested artist, begin testing the titles of the Tunes lexicographically 

            if (compare == 0)   {

                String testTitle = currentTune.title;
                String newTitle = title;
                int compareTitle = newTitle.compareTo(testTitle);

                // The new title comes before the tested title lexicographically

                if  (compareTitle < 0)  {

                    Tune newNode = new Tune(artistName, title);

                    // If the tested Tune was the first Tune in the alphabetical List, insert the new Tune as the new beginning of the alphabetical Linked List

                    if  (theListAlph == currentTune)    {

                        insertNewFirst(newNode, currentTune, theListPop);

                    }

                    // Inserting the new Tune in all other locations in the alphabetical Linked List

                    else    {

                        insertBeforeNotFirst(newNode, currentTune, theListPop);

                    }

                    temp = 1;

                }

                //The titles are the same
                //The same tune cannot be entered twice

                if  (compareTitle == 0) {

                    temp = 2;

                }

            }       

            // The new tune comes last alphabetically, it will be added to the end of the List

            if  (currentTune.nextAlph == null && temp == 0) {

                Tune newNode = new Tune(artistName, title);
                currentTune.nextAlph = newNode;
                newNode.prevAlph = currentTune;
                currentTune = theListPop;
                while   (currentTune.nextPop != null)   {

                    currentTune = currentTune.nextPop;

                }

                currentTune.nextPop = newNode;
                newNode.prevPop = currentTune;
                temp = 1;

            }

            currentTune = currentTune.nextAlph;

        }

    }

    return temp;

}
```

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: You're *printing* 'closing the server', but are you closing anything?

Comment: Further down in the code, the individual thread's IO is closed as well as the thread itself.  It looks like:


     // Close IO and clientThread
   
   in.close();
   out.close();
   incomingConnection.close();

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `out.flush();` after `out.println("2");`.

Comment: Tried that, caused the thread to catch a null pointer exception.  Not sure if this means my thread is coded wrong or that's just not the solution.

Comment: Okay. So at least we know the server is processing the request now. Yes?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so.  As I said, I've tested it with A telnet client typing in '2' myself and it works fine there.  So I believe it just has something to with readline();  But I'm new at this, so I really can't be sure.

Comment: Let's see the stack trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at TuneList.listAlphabetically(TuneList.java:184)
        at clientThread.run(LikeTunesServer.java:290)

You mean this right?  That's what I figure you mean from a cursory search of what a stack trace is; I've never had to use it before.  Anyway, line 184 of Tunelist.java is this:  result = currentTune.returnTune();... which returns a string.  And line 290 of the server thread is:  String result = new String(LikeTunesServer.tl.listAlphabetically());  Sorry if I missed anything.  And thanks for trying to help me with this :)

Comment: So, it looks like currentTune is null and you're trying to invoke the returnTune() method from a null reference. Let's see the code for the addTune() and listAlphabetically() methods.

BTW, regarding the line 

    String result = new String(LikeTunesServer.tl.listAlphabetically());

It isn't necessary to use the String constructor. Just do

    String result = LikeTunesServer.tl.listAlphabetically();

Comment: Added those methods to the original question.  And cheers for the tip.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Would suggest to update client to read response from server after initial insert in case there was an error. Also, verify that length() is returning the correct result. Otherwise, I would suggest using `while (currentTune != null)` instead of the `for(...)`. That will get around the null ptr exception at least.  
Anyway, I think we've resolved your initial problem which was hanging on the reader.